# No custom/authorization Headers in MVC 5 controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, http-headers

I have an MVC 5 ViewController which does not accept headers from an Ajax call. The ajax call origin is a different website then the controller.

The Ajax call looks like:

```
window.jQuery.ajax({
       url: 'http://localhost:54155/TestView',
       headers: {'Authorization': 'token'},
       cache: false,
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       method: 'Get',     
       dataType: 'json',
       data: {}
    }).success(alert('succes?'))
        .error(alert('failed'))
    });
```

Cors is enabled on the controller side:

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>        
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />       
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

And I'm trying to reach this controller:

```
public class TestViewController : Controller
    {           
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
           var keys = Request.Headers.AllKeys;
           return View();
        }
    }
```

If I send the request to a WebApi based on a WEP API 2 controller, the headers are ok. If I send a request with postman to the mvc controller the headers are ok as well.

The Headers contain the header Access-Control-Request-Headers, which has the value authorization. But Request.Headers["Authorization"] is null.

Custom headers like X-MyHeader turn up as value from Access-Control-Request-Headers, but when used like a key, they are all null.

Which part am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same kind of issue - but this might resolve your problem

1. Install `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` from NuGet - Run this command
   (`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`) in your package
   manager console - this will install your Cors
2. Remove your access allow origin code from your `Web.config` file
3. If it is Web Api add the below cod in your `WebApiConfig.cs` if not try to add in your `Gloabl.asax`

`var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*", "*");
 config.EnableCors(cors);`

You will be wondering where that method `EnableCors()` will come `using System.Web.Http.Cors;` add this line in your using and see the magic

This might solve your problem - Finally its not a good idea to access your MVC controller from different domain try you use **WebApi**

If you want to access your MVC controller try out your ajax code form the same domain 
Because WebApi is stateless but MVC is kind of session - Thanks happy coding !!